# Is it still REST if we identify resources with URLs which contain query string components?

Tags: rest, uri

1) I assume *query string component* of an URL is also considered as being a part of identity of a *resource*?

2) If it indeed is considered as being a part of identity, are there any reasons why in REST we can't/shouldn't identify *resources* with URLs which contain *query string components*?

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide some examples of what exactly you mean? I think I know what you are referring to, but don't want to go barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: @thecoshman: I apologize for late reply -  Assuming "http: //yourdomain.com/orders" represents a collection of resources, then we could filter the result with query parameter orderId=1000 to get a specific resource R. But is "http: //yourdomain.com/orders?orderId=1000" considered a unique identifier of R or does this URL represent a (filtered?) collection of resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you root question is about using a query that would return a unique item.

```
/orders?ID=8
```

which would be the same resource as

```
/order/8
```

So there we have two URIs for the same resource. You might be asking is that ok, and it is perfectly fine to have multiple URIs to get the same resource. Generally you should link to a more 'canonical' URI, the shortest 'path' (hierarchally speaking) for a resource.

You shouldn't rely on query parameters generally, as it tends to lead towards awkward API designs. For example, if you want to know all the orders made by bob, you might be tempted to think "well, I'm filtering the orders" and so do

```
/orders?users=bob
```

Where as better way of thinking is "I want all users, just bob, just his orders", so you would instead do

```
/users/bob/orders
```

This is a simple URI that you would be able to link to from the 'user resource' for bob. Sadly though, this second approach can get a bit awkward when you want to say, look at orders from multiple users

```
/users/jack,jill,alice,bob/orders
```

It's workable, but very odd looking.

Comment: If you need nonhierarchical filtering in between the path I would suggest using matrix-parameters like `/users;name=jack,jill,alice,bob/orders`

Comment: Yeah that could work too, but again, it's not very nice to present to users. I guess this is where the idea of being able to provide bits of logic comes into play. You can provide the logic for building that URI from a selection of users, checkboxes maybe.

Answer (score 3):

If the resource you are addressing with a URL represents a collection of resources like `http://yourdomain.com/customers` it's a valid restful way to filter the result with query-parameters:

```
http://yourdomain.com/customers?minSalary=2000&maxAge=50
```

So yes, query-parameters are meaningful for identifying resources.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, hopefully you'll still read it: Assuming "http: //yourdomain.com/orders" represents a collection of resources, then we could filter the result with query parameter orderId=1000 to get a specific resource R. But is "http: //yourdomain.com/orders?orderId=1000" considered a unique identifier of R or does this URL represent a (filtered?) collection of resources?

Comment: Depends on how your resource looks like. I would return a List of orders where each entry contains maybe a id, rel, and link to the resource. So you can still query for `/orders?id=4&id=5`. The resource itself would be available under `/orders/4`. Here I'd return the whole order-data.

Comment: But if we ignore for the moment what the best practice should be, is "http: //yourdomain.com/orders?orderId=1000" considered a unique identifier of a resource or of a (filtered) collection?